# How to change Joomla 1.5 base URL dynamically based on the protocol used for URL(http/https)

Tags: configuration, joomla, https

I have website developed on Joomla 1.5.25. I have set up ssl on my server for providing secure transaction for the payment section.I want to apply https to the certain part of the site(payment/login pages) and want rest of all on HTTP. I figured out a way through htaccess  to have specific pages on https.But the problem is that page links/resources still referring HTTP and because of that browser showing that page is not secure.The problem is that live site URL in configuration.php is set to http. If I change it to https its working fine.But then it does same for HTTP pages also.Which I am not sure is good for the seo.

I think this can be solved if system can handle it dynamically based on the current protocol.So if some one using HTTP then it should use HTTP version and if https then use https.I am not sure if joomla is already providing any solution to this.And if yes then why its not working for my site.Please suggest some way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla! 1.5 you can specify that `HTTPS` is used on particular menu items. This option is available on every menu type as it's a "System" parameter.

If you look at the image below you will see the last line `SSL Enabled` with options of `Off`, `Ignored` (the default) and `On`.

Set this to **On** to have force SSL(`HTTPS`) on that page. (**Off** will force `HTTP` to be used) and **Ignore** will allow whatever the browser asks for.

[image: Joomla! 1.5 Menu Items System Parameters]

*SEO is not affected by the protocol being secure or not.*